# Use particle location as driver variable

Tags: particles, drivers

I wanted to animate this hexgrid I made with particle systems using drivers, but I can't find any way to use the particle x location (or y or any particle-specific data) as a variable for a driver, and using the hexagonal object I use as render for the particles' location makes the particles not update seperately; they all update according to the x location of the original object.

Is there any way to use drivers on particles and make them use variables from the particles.

Comment: I think there is no way to access that property. You could resort to the animation nodes addon. You can access particle proprerties with that addon.

Comment: That does allow for using the particles as a variable, but I can't find a way to use particles as an output on that.

Comment: Nvm I found a way - using object instancing in animation nodes

Comment: If you have an acceptable solution, please post it as an answer.

Comment: working on that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is the one Leander suggested; installing the *animation nodes* addon, then using a node setup that looks like this (the highlighted part makes it so you can animate particles seperately):
[image: Node setup; highlighted part allows for animating particles seperately]

Comment: This didn't work for me, but I can't imagine what I'm doing wrong. You wouldn't happen to have a .blend you could [post](https://blend-exchange.com/), would you?

Comment: no, sorry. I switched computers since I made that answer and have not transferred all my files. Maybe you could send your defect file so I can take a look?