# How to use the age of a particle to change a modifier of a particle itself?

Tags: particles

I would like to know if there is any simple way to use the age of a particle to drive any parameter of the particle itself. For instance, Assuming the particle to target an object with modifiers, I would like the age to change a parameter of one of those modifiers.

- Using the shaders nodes, we can easily change the color depending on the particle's age.
- We can use a texture to change the size of the particle (despite I find this a little cumbersome and counter intuitive).
- I tried using AN (animation nodes) but I only found a way to change the location or forces or only one particle.

I am pretty new to blender, I know we can use scripts and drivers but I never made use of them.

[Edit]
Okay I found this solution [using AN](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86595/use-particle-location-as-driver-variable)
It might be possible to then modify the data path's value of any particle's instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way I just found is to use animation node (here version 2.1.8) and to loop on the particles object. Here is the graph I made:
[image: Data path changed using the particle age]

Note: this is only a minimal setup to have something working (the result is not really useful/pleasant for a real animation), also for some reason I am unable to set a modifier into the "Object Data Path Output > Path" field. Only object specific data are working.

My scene only contains a cone for the particle and a cube for the emitter.

[image]

[image]